# deserializing JSON file to Class that contains dictionary with dynamic key

Tags: c#, json, dictionary, serialization, json.net

I am trying to deserialize a JSON file to an object in c# that has a slightly different structure than the file itself using Newtonsoft.

The file is structured like this:

```
PointProperty:
{
    "DataPointType": Foo
    "PointTypeProperties: [
          {
               "PropertyName":
               "PropertyValue":
               "Requirement":
          },
          etc.
     ]
}
```

I am trying to serialize the JSON file into a PointProperty and PointTypeProperty class:

```
    public class PointProperty
    {
        public string DataPointType { get; set; }

        public Dictionary<String,PointTypeProperty> PointTypeProperties { get; set; }
    }

    public class PointTypeProperty
    {
        public string PropertyValue { get; set; }
        public string Requirement { get; set; }

    }
```

In a way where the key to the PointTypeProperties dictionary would be PropertyName in the JSON file. Is there any way I can do this with a custom deserializer?

For example:

```
PointProperty:
{
    "DataPointType": Alarm
    "PointTypeProperties: [
          {
               "PropertyName": AlarmCheck
               "PropertyValue": False
               "Requirement": Mandatory
          },
          etc.
     ]
}
```

Would be deserialized into the classes like:

``

```
public class PointTypeProperty
{
    public string PropertyValue = False
    public string Requirement = Mandatory

}

public class PointProperty
{
    public string DataPointType = Alarm

    public Dictionary<String,PointTypeProperty> PointTypeProperties = {"AlarmCheck": PointTypeProperty}
}
```

Comment: Hi Jacob. I confess I'm a little unsure of what you're asking for. When you say you're trying to serialize "the JSON file" do you mean deserialize? e.g. Data that is persisted on a storage medium in the JSON format -> deserialize into an object in your code. There are decorations you can use to deserialize a field to a differently named class field.  e.g. [JsonProperty("field_name_in_file")] public string FieldName {get; set;} -- this will put any value found in the file under "field_name_in_file" into the class property FieldName.  This is my best guess as to what you're asking.

Comment: Can you show some valid input Json, and what you want the result to be?

Comment: Yes that's a typo on my part. I meant deserialize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a custom serializer. You can use a DTO which you can convert easily to your class.

`PointTypeProperties` is logically an array in the JSON, so make a DTO which models that array:

```
public class PointPropertyDto
{
    public string DataPointType { get; set; }
    public PointTypePropertyDto[] PointTypeProperties { get; set; }
}

public class PointTypePropertyDto
{
    public string PropertyName { get; set; }
    public string PropertyValue { get; set; }
    public string Requirement { get; set; }
}
```

Deserialize the JSON to the DTO graph instead:

```
string json = @"
{
    ""DataPointType"": ""Foo"",
    ""PointTypeProperties"": [
          {
               ""PropertyName"": ""Some name"",
               ""PropertyValue"": ""Some value"",
               ""Requirement"": ""Some requirement""
          }
     ]
}";

var deserializedDto = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PointPropertyDto>(json);
```

Then, convert from the DTO to your original class:

```
var deserialized = new PointProperty
{
    DataPointType = deserializedDto.DataPointType,
    PointTypeProperties = deserializedDto.PointTypeProperties.ToDictionary(p => p.PropertyName, p =>
        new PointTypeProperty
        {
            PropertyValue = p.PropertyValue,
            Requirement = p.Requirement
        })
};
```